# Rails 3 NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

Whenever i tried to use

```
Table.create :a=>"a", :b=>"b"
```

or

```
tab=Table.new
tab.a="a"
tab.b="b"
tab.save!
```

produces

> NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

my table model is

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base  
 set_table_name "table"
 set_primary_key "id"
end
```

Comment: Calling an SQL table `table` is a call for trouble. At least call it `tables` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone has stated, `TABLE` is a reserved word. For future reference, if you *really* wanted to use these reserved words, in your sql queries(I know you are using the AR abstraction), you would have to use backticks like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE`
```

However I would highly suggest changing your table name. One other thing to note is that you do not have to set your primary key to `id` because rails by default uses `id` for the PK.

Answer (score 2):

`TABLE` is reserved word in MySQL.

For more reserved words checkout:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html